# Opening Report Builder report in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report created using a Report Builder 3.0. Now I want to manage it in Visual Studio using SSRS but even though the file type is `.rdl`, when I click to open the report what I get is `XML` file. How do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 you would need the [Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767(v=sql.105).aspx) to open the `rdl` file in designer mode.

You would need to create a business intelligence project - Report Server project.

[image]

Under your report project go to reports add existing item and browse to your rdl file.

[image]

For Visual Studio 2012 you would need [SSDT-BI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856966(v=sql.110).aspx) to open your BI projects.

Visual Studio 2014 - [SSDT-BI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856966(v=sql.120).aspx)

For visual Studio 2015 SSDT-BI will be called as SSDT. You can use the SSDT for your BI needs.

[Download link for latest SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx).